# Matching Bloomberg Data in R

Tags: r, time, series, bloomberg

Working with the Rblpapi package, I receive a list of multiple data frames when requesting securities. (Equaling the number of securities requested)

My problem is the following one: Let's say:
I request daily data for A and B from 01.10.2016 - 31.10.2016
Some data for A is missing during that time, while B has,
also some data for B is missing, when A has.

So basically:

```
list$A                  
       date       PX_LAST
    1  2016-10-03 216.704
    2  2016-10-04 217.245
    3  2016-10-05 216.887
    4  2016-10-06 217.164
    5  2016-10-10 217.504
    6  2016-10-11 217.022
    7  2016-10-12 217.326
    8  2016-10-13 216.219
    9  2016-10-14 217.275
    10 2016-10-17 216.751
    11 2016-10-18 218.812
    12 2016-10-19 219.682
    13 2016-10-20 220.189
    14 2016-10-21 220.930
    15 2016-10-25 221.179
    16 2016-10-26 219.840
    17 2016-10-27 219.158
    18 2016-10-31 217.820

list$B
       date       PX_LAST
    1  2016-10-03 1722.82
    2  2016-10-04 1717.82
    3  2016-10-05 1721.14 
    4  2016-10-06 1718.40
    5  2016-10-07 1712.40        
    6  2016-10-11 1700.33
    7  2016-10-12 1695.54
    8  2016-10-13 1689.62
    9  2016-10-14 1693.71
   10  2016-10-17 1687.84
   11  2016-10-18 1701.10
   12  2016-10-19 1706.74
   13  2016-10-21 1701.16
   14  2016-10-24 1706.24
   15  2016-10-25 1701.20
   16  2016-10-26 1699.92
   17  2016-10-27 1694.66
   18  2016-10-28 1690.96
   19  2016-10-31 1690.92
```

As you see they have a different number of obervations and dates are also not equal. For example: 5. observation for A is on 2016-10-10 and for B is on 2016-10-07.

So what I need is a means to combine both data frames. My idea was a full range date range (every day) where I add the PX_values for corresponding dates of A and B. After that I could delete empty rows.

Sorry for bad formatting, this is my first post here. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing the `PX_LAST` column name to reflect the appropriate series (i.e. `PX_LAST_A`), and then merge on `date`.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment, I solved my problem already.

Comment: @DanielMetko You can answer your question yourself in the answer section below - that will help future readers.